# Pentaho version 8 Kafka Stream-consumer setup

Tags: apache-kafka, pentaho-data-integration

There is not any clear step by step documentation for 8 Kafka Consumer. What did I miss here?

I can see that kafka consumer is receiving messages based on "input" field (See capture1.jpg ) but no output to logs.

I am attaching my ktr files.

Attaching my logs and the warning I see on the Spoon.

[image]